# Is it possible to get element by class in selenium webdriver ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I have a class like this:

```
<div class="qa-share-message ng-isolate-scope ng-valid ta-root
ng-dirty focussed" ng-model="message" text-angular="">
```

I want to type in this field. i have tried this:

```
driver.find_elements(:class, "qa-share-message").send_keys("This is a test message")
```

After running the code it shows error:

```
undefined method `send_keys' for [#<Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x65990040 id="33">]:Array
```

Is it possible to get element by class?

Comment: If you are looking for only one element, perhaps you meant to use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`?

Comment: Tried with find_element but noting happens. This line was skipped and rest of the code was executed. Also there was no error in console.

Answer (score 1):

You obviously **got** element**s** by class. Look:

> undefined method `send_keys' for [# Selenium::WebDriver::Element:0x65990040 id="33"]:Array

the error above clearly says: the call to `find_elements` succeeded and returned an `Array` instance, containing `Element`s. Everything you now need is to either `send_keys` to each found element:

```
driver.find_elements(:class, "qa-share-message").each do |e|
  e.send_keys("This is a test message")
end
```

or to send it to one of them, e.g. to the very first one:

```
driver.find_elements(:class, "qa-share-message")
      .first
      .send_keys("This is a test message")
```

Comment: Tried your code, but no hope. It looks like this statement has been skipped cause there is no error.

Comment: You have asked: “Is it possible to get element by class?” The answer above correctly answers this question. Whether you have some other questions, please, post them separately.